# What is android:layout_marginStart

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

I would like to add some space between the left display border and an ImageView. Android SDK made me aware of "android:layout_marginStart".

> Consider adding android:layout_marginStart="10dp" to better support right-to-left layouts

Why should I use `android:layout_marginStart="10dp"` instead of `android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"`? I have never done so and never encountered any problems with so-called "right-to-left layouts".

Comment: *to better support right-to-left layouts*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`start` and `end` are the same as `left` and `right` for left-to-right (LTR) languages. For right-to-left (RTL) languages (Arabic, Hebrew, etc.), `start` and `end` reverse and become equivalent to `right` and `left`, respectively.

This [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) post gets into a bit more detail.

Answer (score 3):

Some APIs were introduced to support languages that use a right to left reading direction e.g Arabic and Hebrew.

One of which is android:layout_marginStart

See the link for more info : http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL