# Android marginLeft vs marginStart: Conflicts & Priority

Tags: android, android-layout

According to this question ([StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934106/what-is-androidlayout-marginstart)) is marginStart the same as marginLeft (under the premise of Left-to-Right flow).

**What happens when there are conflicting values?**

Let's say marginStart is 24dp and marginLeft is 32dp. Has then one priority over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens when there are conflicting values?
>
> Let's say marginStart is 24dp and marginLeft is 32dp. Has then one
>   priority over the other?

In both `left-to-right` and `right-to-left` layouts `layout_marginStart` will be used.

**Note:** If your min sdk version is less than 17 use both `start/end` and `left/right` because `start/end` are not recognized and will be ignored, else you should use only `start/end` as it will automatically take care of `left-to-right` and `right-to-left` layouts.

Comment: Ah, okay. I get it. They left marginLeft in there because of downwards-compatibility. Thanks a lot for your answer.